# SOCKETS (Networking) - TicTacToe Game

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming, tic-tac-toe

I am creating my own Tic-Tac-Toe game.

At this stage I am trying to add a networking functionality to it, which would allow two players in the same network - but in different devices - to play against each other.

One of the first things I am trying to do is to send the game via server to the client, but in this case the function **game()** (which runs the whole game) is opening on the server side and not on the client's side.

Special highlight to the last part of the code (Main function)!

Any help?

```
def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5000

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(1)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                    break
            print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

            data = game
            print ("sending: ")
            conn.send(data().encode())

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a Game class to replace the game function. Then, both client and server (assuming that you want a game between a client and a server) should maintain a Game instance. In this way, when client makes a move, it can update its own Game instance, and send the update to server. Server can do the same thing to keep the Game going.
Anyway, this [repo](https://github.com/houluy/Chatroom) may help you on this issue. It's not well completed, even no error handling. But its game function can work.